# C# to C++ Array?

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I have a library provided, which i know uses C++.
I imported the DLL as such:
`[DllImport("pst")] private static extern int pst_get_sensor(ref PSTSensor sensor);`
The PSTSensor is a struct, in a C++ example it was defined as such:

```
struct PSTSensor
{
        char    name[80];       /**< Device name */
        int     id;             /**< Device identifier (for other tracking interfaces */
        float   pose[16];       /**< Device pose estimate as row-major matrix */
        double  timestamp;      /**< Time the data was recorded */
};
```

The problem is, that besides an Int and a Double, it uses a Float, and more importantly an array. An array is something way different between C# and C++. When using this struct to call `pst_get_sensor(ref sensor);` the entire development environment crashes on me when running the code.

I currently do my struct in C# like this:

```
struct PSTSensor{
        public char[] name;
        public int id;
        public float[] pose;
        public double timestamp;
    }
```

My question is, how do i create an array that C++ understands, and properly returns? Is this even possible?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Smiley

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your C# struct needs to define the inline array lengths. And the `name` field is best declared as a string in the C# code. That makes it much easier for you to work with it.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
struct PSTSensor
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
    public string name;
    public int id;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
    public float[] pose;
    public double timestamp;
}
```

The struct layout attribute is optional here, because it just re-states default values. But you may choose to keep it in order to be explicit about your intent.

Comment: Ok, let me try this out. In the mean time. I probably will need to read up on what marchalling is, and what unmanagedTypes are (i do not code in C++ yet, so that makes this so much harder to understand)

Comment: This MSDN topic will help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h(v=vs.110).aspx#cpcondefaultmarshalingforstringsanchor3

Comment: It works, awesome! i decided to keep the optional line for future reference. Thanks a million, 3 teachers could not get me my answer, and i saw marshaling in other context, but i did not get what it does or how to implement it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use fixed keyword with allowing unsafe code option in properties

```
unsafe struct PSTSensor
{
    public fixed char name[80];
    public int id;
    public fixed float pose[16];
    public double timestamp;
}
```

This will be the declaration and for using passing it to cpp function you can call like this

```
unsafe 
{
   PSTSensor stSensor = new PSTSensor();
   testfunc(stSensor); //function call cpp
}
```

Comment: But now your struct is much more onerous to use and you are compelled to use `unsafe` code. Yes you can do this, but you should not.

Comment: i agree for unsafe ,but how is it more onerous?

Comment: Ask yourself how you read and write the fixed arrays? And then compare with the variant that does not use unsafe code. Finally, not that `char` is two bytes wide in C#. So you'd need to use `fixed byte name[80]` and how would you access that?