# Encoding issue with String to Bytes conversion

Tags: c#, character-encoding

I am trying to convert a string to bytes and vice versa..i have seen the previous question of converting string to byte array on this site..but my problem is something else

Here is my code

```
byte[] btest = new byte[2];
btest[0] = 0xFF;
btest[1] = 0xAA;
UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();
string str = enc.GetString(btest); //here i get a string with values str = '��'

//I had a byte array of size 2 with the above contents
//Here i am trying to convert the string to byte array
byte [] bst = enc.GetBytes(str); //On this step i get a byte array of size 6 
//and bst array contents as {239,191,189,239,191,189}

//In this step i try to convert the value back to btest array by taking the index
btest[0] = Convert.ToByte(str[0]); //on this line i get an exception
//Exception : Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte.
btest[1] = Convert.ToByte(str[1]);
```

Shouldn't the GetBytes return me a byte array of size 2,what wrong am i doing??
I want bst[0] to contain the same value which i have assigned to btest[0] .

Thanks

Comment: Please try to be more clear in your Question titles. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your original byte input is not valid UTF-8 (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description)), in that it doesn't represent any unicode code point. As a result the invalid data is converted to �. In the end, that is a character like any other, so if you try to convert that back to bytes, it won't generate your initial wrong byte sequence, but the proper byte sequence to represent that unicode code point (twice).

The character cannot be represented as a single byte, hence `Convert.ToByte` throws an `OverflowException`.

If you were to change your original input to a valid byte sequence, say:

```
btest[0] = 0xDF;
btest[1] = 0xBF;
```

You will see that the `enc.GetBytes(str)` call actually results in a two-byte array again.

Answer (score 0):

Character with codepoint `0xFF 0xAA` is invalid in UTF-8 encoding, thus it's converted to `�`

References:

- See valid codepoint ranges on a corresponding wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description

Comment: but when i convert it back why dont i get the correct output??

Comment: @singh: it is correct. The `str` equals to `��`, each of which is represented by 3 bytes codepoint

Comment: actually i am passing the string constructed from here to c++ but i dont get the correct value there as explained by David Heffernan in his answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145911/c-sharp-to-c-array/20146297#20146297

Comment: on the other hand if i use kunal's answer in the same question i get the correct value

Comment: @singh: you got 2 answers that explain the behaviour. If you perform `1 + 1` the returned value would be `2`, not `5` even if you really want it.

Comment: "if i use kunal's answer" --- I don't see where they convert a byte array into a UTF-8 encoded string and back.

Comment: i use fixed byte array instead of char array so passing the value directly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43823/discussion-between-singh-and-zerkms)